# Rails 4.1 w/ Heroku: DalliError: No server available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, memcached, dalli

I am using:

- `Rails 4.1.0rc2`
- `Heroku`
- `gem 'memcachier'`
- `gem 'dalli'`

If I use caching from the console, it works:

```
irb(main):010:0> Rails.cache.write("foo", "bar")
=> 1297036692682702848
irb(main):011:0> Rails.cache.read("foo")
=> "bar"
```

But if I set the cache using Rails.cache.fetch in the application, and attempt to read via the console, I get this.

```
Rails.cache.read([School, "California", [], School.where(state: "California").all.map(&:updated_at).max, "city_filters"])
Dalli::Server#connect mc3.dev.ec2.memcachier.com:11211
Dalli/SASL authenticating as 451265
Dalli/SASL authenticating as 451265
Dalli/SASL: 451265
Dalli/SASL: 451265
=> [{:type=>"city", :value=>"San Francisco", :count=>11, :current=>false}]
```

But when I run this in the app, it does a new search each time.

```
Completed 200 OK in 8481ms (Views: 1151.4ms | ActiveRecord: 246.6ms)
```

Caching works locally (it's not a full cache).

```
Completed 200 OK in 655ms (Views: 244.5ms | ActiveRecord: 74.5ms)
```

How can I get memcached/dalli working? I had this working in a different app; seems like the same set up to me.

Comment: You ever figure it out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you provision memcachier addon on heroku and that you have its credentials in your environment (run: heroku config). Also make sure your memcachier & dalli gems are not nested in any gem group so that they are available in production.

Answer (score -4):

Are you using a free paln on heroku ?
You might need to add **dynos** on heroku to boost up processing speed of your application on heroku.

check out : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

Comment: I am using the free version but I thought dynos didn't help with speed. Even still, shouldn't I still see an attempt to read the cache in the logs?